# How to use xpath to extract text in more than one label of html scripts

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, scrapy

Suppose I have many html scripts like this:

`<div style="clear:both" id="novelintro" itemprop="description">you are foolish!<font color=red size=4>I am superman!</font></div>`

I want to use xpath to extract the text: you are foolish! I am superman!

However, if i use

`xpath('//div[@id="novelintro"]/text()').extract()`

I can only get "you are foolish!"

while I use:

`xpath('//div[@id="novelintro"]/font/text()').extract()"`

I can only get "I am superman!"

so if you could use only one xpath expression to extract the whole sentence which is "you are foolish! I am superman!"

And more unlucky, in the html script above, it is "`<font>`" label, but in my other script, there are many other labels, for example:

to extract "hi girl I love you!" in the follow script:
`<div style="clear:both" id="novelintro" itemprop="description">hi girl<legend >I love you!</legend></div>`

to extract "If I marry your mother then I am your father!" in the follow script:

`<div style="clear:both" id="novelintro" itemprop="description">If I<legend > marry your mother<div>then I am your father!</div></legend></div>`

if you could use only one xpath expression to adapt all of the html scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath's `string()` function, which recursively converts a single node to string (the optional `.` refers to the current node):

```py
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

def node_to_string(node):
    return node.xpath("string(.)").extract()[0]

# ------------------------------------------------------

body = """<body>
  <div style="clear:both" id="novelintro" itemprop="description">you are foolish!<font color=red size=4>I am superman!</font></div>
  <div style="clear:both" id="novelintro2" itemprop="description">hi girl<legend >I love you!</legend></div>
  <div style="clear:both" id="novelintro3" itemprop="description">If I<legend > marry your mother<div>then I am your father!</div></legend></div>
</body>"""

hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(text=body)

# single target use
print node_to_string(hxs.xpath('//div[@id="novelintro"]'))
print 

# multi target use
for div in hxs.xpath('//body/div'):
    print node_to_string(div)
print 

# alternatively
print [node_to_string(n) for n in hxs.xpath('//body/div')]
print
```

output

```
you are foolish!I am superman!

you are foolish!I am superman!
hi girlI love you!
If I marry your motherthen I am your father!

[u'you are foolish!I am superman!', u'hi girlI love you!', u'If I marry your motherthen I am your father!']
```

Note that there are spaces missing because they are missing in the source. `string()` handles whitespace the same way a browser would.

Comment: That is what I need!!!! Thanks a lot!!!   Could I write this brilliant method in my blog?

Comment: Sure, if you clearly reference this post (all content on StackOverflow is CC-BY-SA).

Answer (score 0):

If your document is:

```
<outer>This is outer text.<inner>And this is inner text.</inner>More outer text.</outer>
```

and you use the xpath expression: `/outer//text()`
(Read: Any text below 'outer'), the result is a list looking like:

`This is outer text.
    -----------------------
    And this is inner text.
    -----------------------
    More outer text.`